# Pay attention to rare cases?

Tags: halacha-theory

I am searching for a Talmud quote, with specific reference, that says, roughly: We do not pay attention to very rare cases in making our rulings.  I know it exists.  (I am not referring to the Mishna that says that after you've cleaned up rooms for chametz, you don't worry about recontamination, because 'En ledavar sof'.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for מלתא דלא שכיחא לא גזרו בה רבנן.

Randomly chosen example from searching on Bar Ilan: [Bava Metzia 46b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.46b.7?lang=bi).

Comment: "The Sages will decree on a common matter, but not an uncommon matter".  Good, but it was something stronger I read.

Comment: I vaguely recall a statement which I was taught as "we don't rule based on exceptions" but I can't find it.

Comment: so far all I can find is מקרה יוצא מן הכלל, שאינו מלמד על הכלל

Comment: @rosends. What is the reference?

Comment: רש"ר הירש שמות פרשת משפטים פרק כא

Answer (score 3):

Yevamos 119B

> סיפא חזקה לשוק ורובא לשוק והוי ליה זכרים מיעוטא דמיעוטא ומיעוטא דמיעוטא לא חייש רבי מאיר:
>
> and even Rabbi Meir is not concerned about a minority of a minority.

Comment: FWIW as in Heshy’s answer this statement appears several times throughout Shas.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the concept of "בטלא דעתא אצל כל אדם" - a personal opinion being nullified. I know I saw it quoted somewhere in Hilchos Brachos. The concept is that for many laws, we don't pay attention to individual's quirks. Rather, the norm is what we use to determine the law.